# How to Remove Duplicate Domains from a Large List of URLs

Tags: php, regex

I want To remove duplicate domains in the list of URL ,For example Below is the text file

```
http://www.exampleurl.com/something.php
http://www.domain.com/something.php
http://www.exampleurl.com/something111.php 
http://www.exampleurl.com/something111.php 
http://www.exampleurl.com/something222.php
```

I need to remove duplicate domain and i need below list

```
http://www.exampleurl.com/something.php
http://www.domain.com/something.php
```

Below is the code that just remove duplicates in an text file.

```
$text = array_unique(file($filename));

$f = @fopen("promo1.txt",'w+');
if ($f) {
  fputs($f, join('',$text));
  fclose($f);
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$urls = file('domains.txt');
$uniqueDomains = array_reduce (
    $urls,
    function (array $list, $url) {
        $domain = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
        if (!isset($list[$domain])) $list[$domain] = $url;
        return $list;
    },
    array()
);
```

`$uniqueDomains` has the hostname as key. If you don't need (and/or want) it use `array_values($uniqueDomains);`

Comment: Is this right: `$uniqueDomains = array_reduce () {` and not `array_reduce(`? Anyhow the brackets to match up..

Answer (score 0):

To compare on the domains, you can use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url):

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("input.txt");
$lines = explode("\n",$text);
$filtered_domains = array();
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $parsed_url = parse_url($line);
    if(array_search($parsed_url['host'], $filtered_domains) === false)
    {
        $filtered_domains[$line] = $parsed_url['host'];
    }
}
$output = implode("\n", array_keys($filtered_domains));
file_put_contents("output.txt", $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
$lines = file('textfile.txt');
*/
$lines = array(
'http://www.exampleurl.com/something.php',
'http://www.domain.com/something.php',
'http://www.exampleurl.com/something111.php',
'http://www.exampleurl.com/something111.php',
'http://www.exampleurl.com/something222.php'
);
foreach($lines as $line){
 $url_parsed = parse_url($line);
 if(is_array($url_parsed)){
  $host = $url_parsed['host'];
  if(!@$uniques[$host]){
   $uniques[$host] = $line;
  }
 }
}
echo join('',$uniques);
$f = @fopen("promo1.txt",'w+');
if ($f) {
  fputs($f, join("\n",$uniques));
  fclose($f);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove duplicates from an array you can use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). To make your list an array you can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Then to make it a string again you can use implode().

To put this all together you can use the following code:

```
$list = "http://www.exampleurl.com/something.php
        http://www.domain.com/something.php
        http://www.exampleurl.com/something111.php 
        http://www.exampleurl.com/something111.php 
        http://www.exampleurl.com/something222.php";

$newList = implode("\n", array_unique(explode("\n", $list)));
```

Comment: The OP states that he doesn't want to remove duplicate entries, but duplicate domains. E.g. only leave one exampleurl.com and one domain.com...

Comment: yea Calle is correct.To remove duplicate i have given code already,